# Barrel used as stash is no longer neutral

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was using one of the barrels around Raven Rock marketplace as stash. This worked very well for quite a while. Now that I have uncovered most locations, the barrel suddenly went from 'neutral' status to 'owned' and everything in it needs to be 'stolen'.

I am not aware of anything I did to offend the citizens of Raven Rock and it seems that only the marketplace barrels are 'owned'. Using other barrels as stash, e.g. the ones close to the water, still works. Also, people compliment me for clearing the mines.

So - couple of questions:

- Is there a way to tell what might have offended the owner of the marketplace barrel?
- Can it be reversed through gameplay?
- If not, is there an alternative to using the console 'setownership' on every item? It's a three-digit number of objects, so that might take a while. I do not have a follower on the island

Comment: Are you sure the barrel was neutral to start off with? Most stuff in cities are owned by someone, so by putting your stuff in there it may have made your items owned by that NPC.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `setownership` on the barrel? If you hover your cursor over it, you'll get the ID of the barrel, then use `setownership <ID>`

Comment: @Ramirez77 Yes, I took stuff from the barrel at least a dozen times before

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I do not remember seeing an object ID, but I'll try again at home

Comment: That doesn't really prove the barrel wasn't owned since you can take stuff out of an owned container if you put stuff in there. Also for the setownership to work you have to make sure you click on the object you want to change the ownership to. You won't need an ID since it defaults to you.

Comment: @Ramirez77 You will need an ID, since you have to `setownership` per item, by dropping it on the ground and using that ID that starts with `ff`. However, you may be able to select the ID of the barrel and set the ownership that way. I've never tried it so i can't say for sure but it's worth a try.

Comment: @Ramirez77 To be more precise, the HUD now shows `Steal` instead of `Take` when opening the barrel, which it did not do before. Also the items are now displayed with a red font instead of a white one

Comment: @Kaizerwolf yeah and by clicking on the container it sets the target of the setownership console command to that item. The ID you mentioned in the setownership console command refers to who is getting the ownership, not the item you want to make yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this problem would be to use the setownership console command on the barrel to make it belong to you.

The console command is:

> setownership ID
>   Sets ownership of the targeted item. You can set the owner of the targeted item with a faction ID or a character's base ID. If you don't add the parameter, the default owner would be yourself. This can be used to remove the "stolen" tag from any items. Simply drop the item on the ground, open the console, click on the item, and enter the command. It can be difficult to select certain items. If the displayed ID code does not begin with "ff", you have not selected an item, but rather an object in the world (ground texture, light, container, etc.). Can also be used to remove the "owned" attribute of beds and gain the ownership of a stolen horse.

Make sure you click on the barrel which will set the target of your console commands to that object. When you enter the console command you don't need to specify a ID because that refers to who you are giving ownership to. Set ownership defaults to you as the owner unless you provide an ID. You may need to do this with all your items you put in the barrel.

If you aren't one to use console commands, I would recommend not storing anything in a container that isn't owned by you in your house, or guild lodging.

Source: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console

Comment: Remember to be nice all.

Comment: [UPDATE] I have accepted Ramirez77's response as I assume it would work for most people in that kind of situation. The solution for me was rather unexpected, I had to disable the 'Unofficial Skyrim Legendary Edition Patch' which I had installed through the Steam Workshop. And I thought the patch would make things better..

Comment: @Marcus The unofficial patch DOES make things better, IF you start a new game. Installing a mod to a game in progress already is begging for bugs and instability.

Comment: I had just installed the USLE patch, which was probably the problem, but `setownership` (don't type "ID", just make sure you have it selected) worked flawlessly mid-game.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you already have a solution, I just wanted to add a possible explanation for this, which doesn't involve any bugs:

If someone likes you enough, you can take stuff they own without stealing it, as long as each individual item is below a certain value threshold. This mechanic is called [Disposition](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Disposition).

Here's a chart of relationship ranks, and the maximum values of items you can take without stealing:

```
Value   Console name    Item value
-4      Archnemesis     
-3      Enemy   
-2      Foe     
-1      Rival   
0       Acquaintance    
1       Friend          25
2       Confidant       50
3       Ally            100
4       Lover           500
```

So, if the owner of the barrel was fond of you, then you could put cheap items in the barrel and take them out without ever knowing that anyone even owned it.

If you then did something that made them like you less, you could lose your privilege to take the items.

You didn't say what the items were, so maybe none of this applies, but it's a thought.

Comment: It was loot from all allover the island with values from 1 to 2000 gold. Anyway thanks for sharing